# Counter script results in unaligned values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently having trouble aligning the results set by a VBA script.

`Sheet2` is where the data is entered/modified. `Sheet1` is just the interface and grabs the data from `Sheet2` and shows the count. `Sheet2`'s `Worksheet_Change` event handler is where the script updates the counts in `Sheet1!B:B` with the number of times the values in `Sheet2!A:A` have been changed.

At the moment, the script works correctly when the formula in `Sheet1!A:A` copies the value from the corresponding row of `Sheet2!A:A`:

[image: Sheet1 A] [image: Sheet2 A] ➡ [image: Sheet1 B] [image: Sheet2 B]

The first set of images shows the initial state after some values have first been entered into `Sheet2`. The second set shows the result after changing `Sheet2!A2` and `Sheet2!A5`.

This is the script:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change _
            ( _
                       ByVal Target As Range _
            )

  Const s_CheckColumn As String = "A:A"
  Const s_CountColumn As String = "B:B"

  If Intersect(Target, Range(s_CheckColumn)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim rngCell As Range
  For Each rngCell In Intersect(Target, Range(s_CheckColumn))
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(s_CountColumn).Cells(rngCell.Row)
      .Value2 = IIf(.Value2 <> vbNullString, .Value2 + 1, IIf(rngCell.Value2 <> vbNullString, 0, vbNullString))
    End With
  Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Now, however, I want to grab the values from `Sheet2` using an Index-Match formula in `Sheet1!A:A`. This results in some rows being skipped. Unfortunately, this causes some of the counts to be misaligned:

[image: Sheet1 C] [image: Sheet2 C] ➡ [image: Sheet1 D] [image: Sheet2 D]

As you can see, when `Sheet2!A5` is changed, the count in `Sheet1!B5` is updated instead of the count in `Sheet1!B3`.

How would I go about making the script correctly line up the counts with the values in `Sheet1`?

Comment: Which sheet is the `Worksheet_Change` event on? Sheet 1? or Sheet 2?  The `Change` event only fires when a cell is changed, not when it is recalculated to be a different number, so I assume it is in Sheet 2 (as that is where you say you are changing the numbers).  What are the formulas in column B of Sheet 1? (It doesn't sound like the Match portion is being based on column A.)

Comment: You're writing values back to the worksheet that was triggered without disabling events. This is going to run on top of itself.

Comment: Don't try and set .Value2; set .Value from another cell's .Value2.

Comment: @YowE3K 1) Yes, the event handler is in `Sheet2`. 2) There is no formula in `B:B`. It is set in the event handler. 3) I presume the match formula is based on other, undisclosed columns.

Comment: @Jeeped 1) Yes, the script as it was originally posted (before I swapped it for the correct version), would have *safely* caused exactly one extra triggering of the change event every time. The correct version doesn't need events disabled as it only updates `Sheet1` from the `Sheet2` event handler.  2) Can you tell me what detrimental effects or issues are caused by setting `.Value2`? I switched to using `.Value2` for setting so that sets and gets were consistent and I wouldn't accidentally use `.Value` for getting. I haven't noticed any problems since doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to modify the existing code so it works with the new requirement (i.e. rows in `Sheet1` no longer need to correspond to the same numbered rows in `Sheet2`), is to use an extra column in `Sheet1`, say column `C`, whose formula is the `MATCH` part of the `INDEX-MATCH` formula in column `A`.

For your supplied example, the two sheets would then initially look like this:

[image: Sheet1 Initial] [image: Sheet2 Initial]

The row numbers in `Sheet1!C:C` can then be used to find the row in `Sheet1` corresponding to the changed cell in `Sheet2!A:A` (by looking up the changed cell's row in the row numbers). Incrementing *that* row's `B` column keeps the counts correctly aligned:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <The appropriate sheet module>
' Version    : 1.0.2
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447013/1961728
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Private Enum e_MatchType
  GreaterThan = -1
  ExactMatch
  LessThan
End Enum

Private Sub Worksheet_Change _
            ( _
                       ByVal Target As Range _
            )

  Const s_LogSheetName As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_CheckColumn As String = "A:A"
  Const s_CountColumn As String = "B:B"
  Const s_MatchColumn As String = "C:C"
  Const s_InputColumn As String = "A:A"
  Const l_Error As String = "Error"

  If Intersect(Target, Range(s_InputColumn)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  With Worksheets(s_LogSheetName)
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In Intersect(Target, Range(s_InputColumn))
      Dim varMatchingLogRow As Variant
      varMatchingLogRow = Application.Match(rngCell.Row, .Range(s_MatchColumn), e_MatchType.ExactMatch)
      If TypeName(varMatchingLogRow) <> l_Error Then
        If .Range(s_MatchColumn).Cells(varMatchingLogRow) = rngCell.Row Then
          With .Range(s_CountColumn).Cells(varMatchingLogRow)
            .Value2 = IIf(.Value2 <> vbNullString, .Value2 + 1, IIf(rngCell.Value2 <> vbNullString, 0, vbNullString))
          End With
        End If
      End If
    Next rngCell
  End With

End Sub
```

**Note:**

If either the values in `Sheet2!A:A` are ***guaranteed*** to be unique, or it's acceptable to track identical `Sheet2!A:A` value changes in the ***first*** matching `Sheet1!A:A` row, then it *is* possible to get away without using an extra column in `Sheet1`.

Comment: I've put that in but i don't seem to be getting any results from counter of each value in sheet 1 when I change the values in sheet 2..

Comment: What are the formulas you have in `Sheet1!A:A` and `Sheet1!C:C`?

Comment: Sheet 1 A:A grabs values from Sheet 2 A:A. Im not using column C at all

Comment: @Anna **Read my answer carefully,** ***especially the first sentence.***

Comment: I still don't understand where I'm going wrong. Can you show me the formula for one of the cells in row A:A C:C pls

Comment: @Anna Like my first sentence says: I don't have any useful formulae. *You* said you were using an `INDEX-MATCH` formula in `Sheet1!A:A` that was resulting in a reduced set of values in that column. *That* is the formula I asked you for. Like the first sentence also says, the formula in `Sheet1!C:C` is the `MATCH` part of that formula. If you post your formula (i.e. whatever you have in `Sheet1!A:A` that "grabs" the values from `Sheet2!A:A`), I can show you how to break it up into the two columns. (I'm testing with hardcoded values in `C:C` and a simple `INDEX` in `A:A`.)

Comment: @Anna So if you *really* want my testing formula, enter `=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,C1)` in `A1` and fill it down to `A3`. Also enter `1,2,5` in `C:C` like in my screenshot.

Comment: OK I'm trying to replicate my problem into a smaller spreadsheet. So I've incorporated a numbering in  column A:A (1-6) that's how I grab my numbers from sheet 2. Formulae : {=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1A1!, Sheet2!A:A,0))}

Comment: @Anna I'm sorry, but that formula doesn't make any sense. Which cell(s) does it go in? Neither array-entering it in `Sheet1!A1` and then filling down, nor array entering it in `Sheet1!A1:A6` does anything except result in `0`s. It seems to have a self-reference. I presume the typo `Sheet1A1!` should be `Sheet1!A1`?

Comment: It goes in the value I'm trying to look for, in this case it's 20, 12 etc. It worked for my however I had to slightly tweak the code a little thank you! I promise this is the last issue I'm having. What if I have my values in a different column for sheet2. Say I have my values in column C instead of B and I want my results to be pasted into Column D (Sheet1).

Comment: @Anna That's why I have the list of constants at the top of the code. `s_InputColumn`  is the "input column" for `Sheet2`. `s_CountColumn` is the "count column" for `Sheet1`. Just change their values to the required columns, and the code will automatically adjust.